# Python3 Friend of a Friend

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I'm working on this function to find a possible friendship between two people. The friendship system works in a transitive way, that is, if A is a friend of B and B is a friend of C, then A is a friend of C. The dictionary stores the initial relationships (like a graph) and the function parameters are the dictionary and the names of the two people you want to identify if they are friends or not.

```
def findfriendship(people, X, Y):
    if Y in people[X] or X in people[Y]:
        return True

    if len(people[X]) != 0:
        for friend in people[X]:
            return findfriendship(people, friend, Y)

    if len(people[Y]) != 0:
        for friend in people[Y]:
            return findfriendship(people, X, friend)

    return False
```

This is my code and I was successful in identifying a possible friendship between two people as long as one of them have a list of friends not empty, like this:

```
friendships = {'Jordan': ['Shaq'], 'Lebron': [], 'Kobe': [], 'Shaq': ['KD'], 'KD': []}
print(findfriendship(friendships, 'KD', 'Jordan')) -> return True
```

But I can't solve the problem where both have no direct friends, like this:

```
friendships = {'Jordan': ['Shaq'], 'Lebron': [], 'Kobe': ['KD', 'Lebron'], 'Shaq': ['KD'], 'KD': []}
print(findfriendship(friendships, 'Lebron', 'KD')) -> return False
```

it returns False, but Kobe is a friend of them both, so they should be friends.

Can you guys help me trying to solve this problem or do you know a similar question so I can understand this type of concept? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The way you are representing the data is asymmetrical making this a directed graph. This means that Kobe is friends with KD, but KD is not friends with Kobe. If you want an *undirected* graph, Kobe should be in KD and Lebron's list of friends.

Comment: Your `friendships` dict seems to imply Kobe likes KD and Lebron, but KD doesn't like anybody, and neither does Lebron. If you add 'Kobe' to KD and Lebron's list of friends, your code seems to work fine. You might have bugs associated with returning the first result of `findfriendship(people, friend, Y)` though. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: This problem is called *transitive closure*, if that helps you with web searches.

Comment: Think of adding a convenience function to fill your friendship dict in order to get consistent data. The convenience function could accept 2 names to write the data into your dict so that 'Jordan': ['Shaq'] and 'Shaq':['Jordan'] gets added. It will be easier to work with data like that.

Comment: Thank you, guys! I'm gonna work based on your opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if two people are friends would be easy if we could get the full list of friends for either person. Let's write a helper for that:

```py
friendships = {
    'Jordan': ['Shaq'], 'Lebron': [],
    'Kobe': ['KD', 'Lebron'], 'Shaq': ['KD'], 'KD': [],
    "foo": ["bar", "baz"], "bar": [], "baz":[],
}

def buildFriendSet (x, people=None, fSet=None):
    people = people or friendships;       # default value
    fSet = fSet or set([x] + people[x]);  # Friend Set
    changeDetected = False;
    for kPerson, vPersonList in people.items():
        personList = [kPerson] + vPersonList;
        if fSet.issuperset(personList):
            pass;
        elif fSet.intersection(personList):
            fSet = fSet.union(personList);
            changeDetected = True;
    if not changeDetected:
        return fSet;
    return buildFriendSet(x, people, fSet);

print(buildFriendSet('KD'));
# Output: {'Shaq', 'Kobe', 'KD', 'Lebron', 'Jordan'}

print(buildFriendSet('foo'))
# Output: {'baz', 'bar', 'foo'}
```

Once we can compute the set of friends for any person, checking if two people are friends is easy:

```
def checkFriends (x, y, people=None):
    people = people or friendships; # default value
    return (x in people[y] or y in people[x] or
        x in buildFriendSet(y, people)
    );

print(checkFriends('KD', 'Jordan')); # -> True
print(checkFriends('Lebron', 'KD')); # -> True
print(checkFriends('KD', 'foo'));    # -> False
```

**Logic behind `buildFriendSet()`:**

We iterate over `people` and check if the friend-set `fSet` changes. If no change is detected, then we return `fSet` unchanged. Else, we keep looking for more friends.

For a given group of close friends, such as any `personList` above, if everyone in the group is already in `fSet`, there's no need to change `fSet`. This corresponds to the  `.issuperset(.)` check.

Otherwise, if at least one person from `personList` is already in `fSet`, then by association, everyone else must be in it too! We use `.intersection(.)` and `.union()` to check and achieve this, respectively.

**Is everyone their own friend?**

The above implementation assumes that everyone is their own friend. If such behavior isn't desired, using a simple `if`-guard and/or `fSet.remove(.)` should suffice.